# share file from file system to external user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, devextreme

I want to create a link to share a file from devextreme file manager to any user (similar to google drive, can get a link and share that with anybody) in ASP.NET MVC application

Can I use GoogleDriveFileSystemProvider for file sharing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.